# What does "ORA-00917: missing comma" mean?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Below is my insert script, that is a part of my table script. I get an error message on this row/column stating I am missing a comma where `4'x8` is. I'm not sure where to insert the comma to execute the script the way I need it to be.

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('WR3/TT3', 'Steel matting, 4'x8'x1/6", .5" mesh', '17-Jan-12', 18, 5, '119.95', '0.10', 25595);
```

> Error starting at line : 27 in command - INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES
>   ('WR3/TT3', 'Steel matting, 4'x8'x1/6", .5" mesh', '17-Jan-12', 18, 5,
>   '119.95', '0.10', 25595) Error at Command Line : 27 Column : 58 Error
>   report - SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
>   00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Given that this is clearly an Oracle error message, I've removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: Understood for future reference, thank you Bacon!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you do have a single quotes problem.  You used single quotes in the dimensions without escaping them:

```
Steel matting, 4'x8'x1/6", .5" mesh
                ^^^^^ unescaped single quotes
```

To escape single quotes inside a single quoted string you can double them up `''`.  This should work on either MySQL or Oracle.

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT
VALUES ('WR3/TT3', 'Steel matting, 4''x8''x1/6", .5" mesh', '17-Jan-12', 18, 5, '119.95', '0.10', 25595);
```

Comment: Great information Tim! I thought I was able to just use a huge single quote, apparently not :(. This is very helpful. I'm learning small things that I didn't know before. Thank you!

Comment: Another solution could be wrapping into Oracle q literal 
`q'[ Can use  'quotes' here ]'`

Answer (score 1):

***q'[ Can use 'quotes' here ]'*** worked for me.

I was trying below insert:

```
INSERT INTO SITE(SITE_ID,SITE_NAME,SITE_DESC,LIS_SITE_ID,LIS_MODIFIED_DATE,IS_DEFAULT) VALUES (hibernate_sequence.nextval, 'Dawns lab', 'Pat's lab', 0, SYSDATE,'Y');
```

But was throwing

> SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma

But modified like: `INSERT INTO SITE(SITE_ID,SITE_NAME,SITE_DESC,LIS_SITE_ID,LIS_MODIFIED_DATE,IS_DEFAULT) VALUES (hibernate_sequence.nextval, q'[Dawns lab]', q'[Pat's lab]', 0, SYSDATE,'Y');`

Worked for me. Thanks !!!